# “Tomber dans l’escalier”, is “dans” the correct preposition here?

Tags: sens, prépositions

What’s the correct preposition to use for saying “falling down the stairs” in French? Most of the time I see it written as “tomber **dans** l’escalier”. It feels a bit weird, though, since I’m rather inclined to translate “dans” as “in”.

Is “tomber dans l’escalier” a fixed expression? Any idea why “dans” is used here, or where it originally came from? Are other prepositions possible, e.g. “tomber *de* l’escalier” or “tomber *sur* l’escalier”?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are three things with different meanings here

- *Tomber **de** l'escalier* → Falling **from** the stairs
- *Tomber **sur** l'escalier* → Falling **on** the stairs
- *Tomber **dans** l'escalier*

The first two are the same in English and in French. Now for the third one: when one walks up or down the stairs, one is *in* the stairs, as one would be *in* a field or *in* a house. So when one falls while being in the stairs, it makes sense to say that one fell *in* the stairs — *tombe dans l'escalier*.

In a way, *tomber dans l'escalier* is *tomber de l'escalier dans l'escalier*, falling in the stairs from the stairs.

Note that it is not exactly the same as *falling down the stairs*, since it doesn't imply that the fall brought the faller all the way down the stairs, that would be *tomber jusqu'en bas de l'escalier*.

[image: Comment l'on tombe dans un escalier]

Comment: Awesome pictures @Evpok, thanks!

Comment: What a great drawing.

Comment: Nice picture. Painful, but nice!