# L'antécédent étant « affaire » quelle combinaison appliquer, « sur laquelle » ou « dans laquelle » ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

La phrase où le choix doit être fait : « Il m’a proposé une affaire (dans laquelle /sur laquelle ) il y aurait beaucoup d’argent à gagner. »

Je ne sais pas comment employer les prépositions avec les petites choses (je sais que pour une affiche on dit  « sur », mais c'est à peu près tout)

Pourriez-vous m’expliquer s’il vous plaît ?

Answer (score 4):

**I** Savoir quelle préposition employer dans un cas particulier ne se réduit pas à une simple règle ; on fait face dans ce domaine à un ensemble d'usages idiomatiques et les questions de ce type sont traitées individuellement. Voici trois exemples de ces questions (il y en a d'autres) que vous pourrez consulter pour approfondir vos connaissances ;  pour trouver d'autres cas il suffit de faire un peu de recherche dans l'ensemble des question et des réponses qui ont été accumulées.

[garer sur vs garer dans](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/37497/17649)

[Prépositions usuelles unissant « (faire un) tour » et « montagnes russes » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/34554/17649)

[“Tomber dans l’escalier”, is “dans” the correct preposition here?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/5722/17649)

Il y a certains principes basiques cependant pour ce que vous appelez « les petites choses ». « Sur » est utilisé (sauf exceptions) pour les choses planes et d'autres qui ne le sont pas.

- ***choses planes***    table, plancher, feuille,…
- *exceptions*    rue (dans la rue, « sur » est rare),…
- ***choses non planes***    fil (oiseau sur un fil),…

  « Dans » est utilisé pour  les choses qui peuvent contenir de la matière.
- boites, casseroles, maisons, voitures, …

Dans le cas du mot « affaire » l'emploi de la préposition est figuré. Il y a plusieurs possibilités et les deux prépositions sont utilisables.

Si l'affaire est de la sorte qui occupe les personnes seulement pour un court moment avant de passer à une autre affaire, comme dans le cas des affaires d'avocat, on peut utiliser les deux suivant le contexte.

- Il n'a rien à voir *dans* cette affaire. (*« sur » ne peut pas être utilisé dans le présent cas.*)
- Il devraient mettre cet avocat *sur* cette affaire, il est spécialisé dans ce domaine légal. (*« dans » ne peut pas être utilisé dans ce cas-ci.*)

Si l'affaire consiste en une activité permanente, c'est à dire que l'on entend par « affaire » une entreprise, ce n'est pas différent : les deux prépositions sont utilisables selon le contexte.

- Dans cette affaire, il n'y a personne à la tête et c'est la raison de la faillite qui s'annonce.
  *Le contexte se définit comme étant un état de chose à l'intérieur de l'affaire d'où une notion de contenu et la préposition « dans ».*
- Sur cette affaire pèse des charges énormes, ce qui la rend difficile à conserver.
  *Le contexte se définit comme une force extérieure qui agit « sur » l'affaire plutôt que « dans », d'où « sur ».*

**II** Dans la phrase de la question il y a deux possibilité ;

1/ L'affaire est une activité permanente dans laquelle quelqu'un lance quelqu'un d'autre (contexte plutôt rare où quelqu'un est mis à la tête d'une affaire de petite importance parmi un ensemble d'affaires qui  dépendent d'une même direction générale); alors on utilise « dans » uniquement.

- Il m’a proposé une affaire dans laquelle il y aurait beaucoup d’argent à gagner.

2/ L'affaire est une activité momentanée (par exemple en partenariat ou en sous-traitance), avant de passer à une autre affaire ou en tant qu'unique occasion ; alors les deux prépositions sont utilisables.

- Il m’a proposé une affaire (dans laquelle /sur laquelle ) il y aurait beaucoup d’argent à gagner.

Answer (score 4):

J'écarterais la première proposition :

> Il m’a proposé une affaire **sur laquelle** il y aurait beaucoup d’argent à gagner.

simplement car on ne gagne pas « sur une affaire ».

La deuxième utilise en revanche une tournure courante :

> Il m’a proposé une affaire **dans laquelle** il y aurait beaucoup d’argent à gagner.

On peut en effet gagner (ou perdre) « dans une affaire », mais puisque *dans* introduit souvent un lieu, pourquoi ne pas s'affranchir de *laquelle* et dire :

> Il m’a proposé une affaire **où** il y aurait beaucoup d’argent à gagner.

Comment: quid de "avec laquelle" ?

Comment: @LaurentS. Oui, ça me semble aussi possible et j'ai d'ailleurs hésité à le mettre, mais je n'ai trouvé que des occurrences de cette tournure où *affaires* avait un sens judiciaire.